# Why isn´t websphere recognizing my webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, websphere-7

I´ve been working on a webservice with websphere 7 and jaxws.
So if my webservice returns a string, and Integer, and int or a float. When I deploy it websphere recognizes my webservice, but if I change my webservice to return a java bean; it doesn´t recognize my webservice.

Here is my code.
The interface:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface MensajeSMS {
    @WebMethod
    String sendMessage(Long idUsuario, String token, Integer idServicio,
            String mensaje, String contacto, String idMensaje);
}
```

the implementation:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "bisnet.sms.MensajeSMS")
public class MensajeSMSImpl implements MensajeSMS {

    @Override
    public String sendMessage(Long idUsuario, String token, Integer idServicio,
            String mensaje, String contacto, String idMensaje) {
        return "Hola " + idUsuario +" "+ "tu token con Bisnet Corporativo será: " + token
                +". El número telefónico que registraste es: " + idServicio
                + " y tu nombre es: " +mensaje +" " +contacto+ " " +idMensaje ;
    }

}
```

My request:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "sendMessage", namespace = "http://sms.bisnet/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sendMessage", namespace = "http://sms.bisnet/")
public class SendMessage {

    @XmlElement(name = "arg0", namespace = "")
    private Long idUsuario;

    @XmlElement(name = "arg1", namespace = "")
    private String token;

    @XmlElement(name = "arg2", namespace = "")
    private Integer idServicio;

    @XmlElement(name = "arg3", namespace = "")
    private String mensaje;

    @XmlElement(name = "arg4", namespace = "")
    private String contacto;

    @XmlElement(name = "arg5", namespace = "")
    private String idMensaje;

    /**
     * @return the idUsuario
     */
    public Long getIdUsuario() {
        return idUsuario;
    }

    /**
     * @param idUsuario the idUsuario to set
     */
    public void setIdUsuario(Long idUsuario) {
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    }

    /**
     * @return the token
     */
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    /**
     * @param token the token to set
     */
    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    /**
     * @return the idServicio
     */
    public Integer getIdServicio() {
        return idServicio;
    }

    /**
     * @param idServicio the idServicio to set
     */
    public void setIdServicio(Integer idServicio) {
        this.idServicio = idServicio;
    }

    /**
     * @return the mensaje
     */
    public String getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }

    /**
     * @param mensaje the mensaje to set
     */
    public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }

    /**
     * @return the contacto
     */
    public String getContacto() {
        return contacto;
    }

    /**
     * @param contacto the contacto to set
     */
    public void setContacto(String contacto) {
        this.contacto = contacto;
    }

    /**
     * @return the idMensaje
     */
    public String getIdMensaje() {
        return idMensaje;
    }

    /**
     * @param idMensaje the idMensaje to set
     */
    public void setIdMensaje(String idMensaje) {
        this.idMensaje = idMensaje;
    }

}
```

and finally my response:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "sendMessageResponse", namespace = "http://sms.bisnet/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "sendMessageResponse", namespace = "http://sms.bisnet/")
public class SendMessageResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "return", namespace = "")
    private String _return;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     returns String
     */
    public String getReturn() {
        return this._return;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param _return
     *     the value for the _return property
     */
    public void setReturn(String _return) {
        this._return = _return;
    }

}
```

The way it´s now works, but if I change the interface, the implementation and the response so they return a java bean instead of a string; websphere doesn´t recognize my webservice therefore it doesn´t show or generate a wsdl.

Does anyone knows why does this happen??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can the JAX-WS runtime generate the WSDL from your new bean definition (you can see this in the console output)? Where is the bean definition (the Java class), in a shared library? The JAXB annotations are not necessary if you use XML simple types.

Comment: if deploy it and try to open in my navigator the wsdl it doesn´t appear if my webservice returns an object.

Comment: and also I need the jax annotations so I can do the marshalling and unmarshalling in the client side.

Comment: Where is the object class? Is there in a jar? In a shared library? In the same package like the service interface and implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a problem with your webservice or service definition, WebSphere will throw an error during application startup. Usually you can find it in your `SystemOut.log`.

If you run the String-version you should find a log that the Service was started successfully at the same spot.